# Web Services in java Application in Netbeans 7

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I need to add a few Web Services into my simple Java Application project in netbeans. Should I convert my project into "web" or "javaee"?

If yes, how?
if no, then how can I config a web service?

Comment: Google "netbeans web service tutorial" and follow the first 3 results...

Comment: the problem is that I currently have a project. The least I need to do is to convert my project into javaee.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if you can convert an existing project. I would either copy the files or package your existing classes into a jar library and use this library from a new Java EE project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose web services via a Web Application or EJB 3.0. Also, the application should be deployed in a Web Application Server like Tomcat or Glassfish.

To answer to your question, yes, you should take one of these steps, I'll recommend starting with the basics by developing the Web Service in a Web Application. To start developing your web services in NetBeans, follow [Getting started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) tutorial about creating a simple Web Service with SOAP.

Also, I lend you a sample of an application that provides and consume web services [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/5JNH7LQE/WSExample.html)